# How can I let user to input a field from another table and store the primary key to the table that the view belongs to? [ASP.NET MVC EF6 Code-first]

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

First of all, sorry for the confusing question. I am making an intranet web application for internal use with ASP.NET MVC EF6 framework. There are two tables I want to use for a particular function, first is an "employee" table that stores the name, Windows username(*User.Identity.Name*), status(active/inactive) and other information of a user and uses an auto increment "ID" field as primary key. Another table is a "record" table that stores the IDs of 2 users involved in a request and uses an auto increment RecordId field as primary key. EmpAID and EmpBID are 2 foreign keys pointing to the employee table's primary key ID. 
I would like to make a page for creating record which contains an autocomplete textbox that let a user to type in the name keyword of another user and they could pick the user they want from the suggestions similar to  [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g4z0F.jpg). After clicking the create button, a "record" record should be created with EmpAID  being the ID of an employee record with the same Windows username as the currently logged in user, and EmpBID being the ID of an employee record with the name same as the textbox input and status being active. How should I code the controller and view to make this happen? 
Record.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using Interchangesys.Models;

namespace Interchangesys.Models
{
    public enum Status
    {
        Pending, Accepted, Denied, Approved, Deleted
    }
    public class Record
    {
        [Key]
        public int RecordID { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime BeforeDate { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime AfterDate { get; set; }
        public int ShiftIDBefore { get; set; }
        public int ShiftIDAfter { get; set; }
        public int? EmpAID { get; set; }
        public int? EmpBID { get; set; }
        public Status Status { get; set; }
        public string? Reason { get; set; }
        public bool Self_interchange { get; set; }
        public virtual Employee EmployeeA { get; set; }
        public virtual Employee EmployeeB { get; set; }
        //public virtual Shift Shift { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Employee.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace Interchangesys.Models
{
    public enum EStatus
    {
        Active, Inactive
    }
    public class Employee
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Name cannot be longer than 50 characters.")]
        [Display(Name = "Name")] 
        public string FullName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Login Name")]
        public string Login_Name { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Staff Number")]
        public int Staff_No { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Employment Type")]
        public string Employment_type { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Position")]
        public string Position_type { get; set; }
        public int? SkilltableID { get; set; }
        public EStatus EStatus { get; set; }
        public string? Email { get; set; }
        [InverseProperty("EmployeeA")]
        public virtual ICollection<Record> SendRecords { get; set; }
        [InverseProperty("EmployeeB")]
        public virtual ICollection<Record> ReceiveRecords { get; set; }
        public virtual Skilltable Skilltable { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Context

```
using System.Web;
using Interchangesys.Models;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions;

namespace Interchangesys.DAL
{
    public class EmpContext : DbContext
    {
        public EmpContext() : base("EmpContext")
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Record> Records { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Shift> Shifts { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Skilltable> Skilltables { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();

            modelBuilder.Entity<Record>()
                        .HasRequired(m => m.EmployeeA)
                        .WithMany(t => t.SendRecords)
                        .HasForeignKey(m => m.EmpAID)
                        .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Record>()
                        .HasRequired(m => m.EmployeeB)
                        .WithMany(t => t.ReceiveRecords)
                        .HasForeignKey(m => m.EmpBID)
                        .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
        }
    }
}
```

RecordController.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Interchangesys.DAL;
using Interchangesys.Models;

namespace Interchangesys.Controllers
{
    public class RecordController : Controller
    {
        private EmpContext db = new EmpContext();

        // GET: Record
        public ActionResult Index(string acceptedonly)
        {
            ViewBag.recfilterstat  = acceptedonly == "Filtered" ? "All" : "Filtered";
            var records = from s in db.Records
                            select s;
            if (acceptedonly == "Filtered")
            {
                records = records.Where(record => record.Status == Status.Accepted);
            }
            return View(records.ToList());
        }

        // GET: Record/Details/5
        public ActionResult Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Record record = db.Records.Find(id);
            if (record == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(record);
        }

        // GET: Record/Create
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        // POST: Record/Create
        // 若要避免過量張貼攻擊，請啟用您要繫結的特定屬性。
        // 如需詳細資料，請參閱 https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598。
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "RecordID,BeforeDate,AfterDate,ShiftIDBefore,ShiftIDAfter,EmpAID,EmpBID,Reason,Self_interchange,Status")] Record record)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                record.Status = Status.Pending;
                db.Records.Add(record);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(record);
        }

        // GET: Record/Edit/5
        public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Record record = db.Records.Find(id);
            if (record == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(record);
        }

        // POST: Record/Edit/5
        // 若要避免過量張貼攻擊，請啟用您要繫結的特定屬性。
        // 如需詳細資料，請參閱 https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598。
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "RecordID,BeforeDate,AfterDate,ShiftIDBefore,ShiftIDAfter,EmpAID,EmpBID,Reason,Self_interchange,Status")] Record record)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(record).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(record);
        }

        // GET: Record/Delete/5
        public ActionResult Delete(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Record record = db.Records.Find(id);
            if (record == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(record);
        }

        // POST: Record/Delete/5
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            Record record = db.Records.Find(id);
            db.Records.Remove(record);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                db.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
}
```

Create.cs

```
@model Interchangesys.Models.Record

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    
<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Interchange Record</h4>
    <hr />
    <dt>
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

        <div class="form-group">
            &ensp; Requestee Name <p>
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Reason, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmpBID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </p>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            &ensp; Original Shift Date <p>
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.BeforeDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BeforeDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    8:00 - 16:00
                </div>
            </p>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            &ensp; Post-interchange Shift Date <p>
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AfterDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AfterDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    PH
                </div>
            </p>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Reason, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Reason, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Reason, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Self_interchange, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Self_interchange)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Self_interchange, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </dt>
</div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What specifically is the problem? Do you have an issue populating the dropdowns or saving the data?

Comment: I am trying to make it so that when a user type in a name(field belongs in another model) in a view and create new record, the web app will automatically search for the ID of record that its name field matches the typed in name in another model and save that ID in the new "record" record, but I don't know how to write the code for the controller or the view to do that.